# Prototype 1.7 - attribute selectors got broken?

Tags: css, prototypejs, css-selectors, upgrade, sizzle

I recently upgraded from Prototype 1.6.1 to 1.7, and I noticed that a part of my site's JS got broken.

I'm esentially doing this:

```
$$("*[required=1]").each(function (el) {
  // stuff
});
```

This is selecting a bunch of form elements. In 1.6.1, this worked perfectly. Since I upgraded to 1.7, this not only returns the `<select>` elements in my form, but not the `<input>`s...

I know that Prototype changed from their old selector engine to Sizzle in 1.7, so I'm assuming it has to do with that, but I'm surprised something this basic would break...

Am I using the wrong syntax? Any idea how I can work around this, without downgrading to 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, experimenting a bit I got around it, by adding single quotes around the attribute value, but this seems wrong based on the CSS selectors spec, right?
Especially since it IS returning select's, but not input's....

```
$$("*[required='1']").each(function (el) {
  // stuff
});
```

Just posting this in case someone stumbles upon the same thing.